# Utility Class for location functionality on Android using Google Play Services FusedLocationProviderClient API

Tags: java, android

I'm new to Android development and this is my first request for a code review. Constructive criticism is very welcome!

I've written a class to wrap interaction with Google's FusedLocationProviderClient. I'm not sure it's a very good idea though as it's not an Activity class and yet there are parts of it that potentially require user interaction - displaying an alert dialog for example. So any suggestions as to the pros and cons on my approach on that front in particular would be appreciated.

I'm also quite worried about the inner-class that extends FragmentActivity. It's used by one method to provide additional rationale to the user for a permission request if necessary. Firstly, should I be messing around with a FragmentActivity for this? If not why not, and could you suggest a more suitable alternative?

Aside from those specific points any feedback - both good or bad - on how I've gone about this, or how I might better go about it, will be greatly appreciated.

Here's the class (sorry it's quite long!)...

```
/**
 * <h1>Wraps interactions with the Google Play Services FusedLocationProviderClient</h1>
 * <p>
 * Provides an easy way to work with a device's location, including testing for and
 * requesting the necessary permission(s) as needed.
 * </p>
 * <p>
 * Provides several methods for retrieving the device's current or last known location.
 * Also provides methods for obtaining the address details of a location.
 * </p>
 * <p>
 * Requires <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
 * to be present in the app's Manifest.
 * </p>
 * <p>
 * The calling Activity should implement ActivityCompat.OnRequestPermissionsResultCallback
 * to receive and handle the result(s) of a permission request.
 * </p>
 *
 */
public class UserLocationUtility extends LocationCallback
{
    private static final String TAG = UserLocationUtility.class.getSimpleName();


    /**
     * Inner-class defining int constants for use with location requests
     */
    public static class RequestCodes
    {
        static final int CURRENT_LOCATION_ONE_TIME = 0;
        static final int CURRENT_LOCATION_UPDATES = 1;
        static final int LAST_KNOWN_LOCATION = 2;
        static final int SMART_LOCATION = 3;
    }

    /**
     * Inner-class defining int constants for use with reverse Geocoding of address data
     */
    public static class AddressCodes
    {
        static final int ADMIN_AREA = 0;
        static final int CITY_NAME = 1;
        static final int COUNTRY_CODE = 2;
        static final int COUNTRY_NAME = 3;
        static final int FEATURE_NAME = 4;
        static final int FULL_ADDRESS = 5;
        static final int PHONE_NUMBER = 6;
        static final int POST_CODE = 7;
        static final int PREMISES = 8;
        static final int STREET_ADDRESS = 9;
        static final int SUB_ADMIN_AREA = 10;
        static final int SUB_THOROUGHFARE = 11;
    }

    /**
     * Inner-class to provide alert dialog functionality for use with permissions checking
     */
    public static class RationaleAlertDialog extends FragmentActivity
    {

        // Hold a WeakReference to the host activity (allows it to be garbage-collected to prevent possible memory leak)
        private final WeakReference<Activity> weakActivity;
        private static final String TAG = RationaleAlertDialog.class.getSimpleName();


        /** Constructor */
        RationaleAlertDialog(Activity activity){
            // assign the activity to the weak reference
            this.weakActivity = new WeakReference<>(activity);
        }

        public void displayAlert(){
            // Re-acquire a strong reference to the calling activity and verify that it still exists and is active
            Activity activity = weakActivity.get();
            if (activity == null || activity.isFinishing() || activity.isDestroyed()) {
                // Activity is no longer valid, don't do anything
                return;
            }

            // Build the alert
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(activity);
            builder.setTitle("Location Permission Request")
                    .setMessage("This app requires permission to access device location in order " +
                               "to provide location functionality. If you do not grant permission " +
                               "then this functionality will be switched off.")
                    .setCancelable(true)
                    .setNeutralButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                            // Dismiss the dialog
                            dialogInterface.cancel();
                        }
                    });

            // Display the alert
            AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
            alert.show();

        }

    }


    // Hold a WeakReference to the host activity (allows it to be garbage-collected to prevent possible memory leak)
    private final WeakReference<Activity> weakActivity;


    private FusedLocationProviderClient mLocationClient;
    private Context mContext;
    private LocationRequest mLocationRequest;
    private LocationCallback mLocationCallback;
    private boolean mIsReceivingUpdates;
    private Geocoder mGeocoder;


    /** Constructor */
    UserLocationUtility(Activity activity){
        // assign the activity to the weak reference
        this.weakActivity = new WeakReference<>(activity);

        // Hold a reference to the Application Context single object
        this.mContext = activity.getApplicationContext();

        // Instantiate our location client
        this.mLocationClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(mContext);

        // Set the request state flag to false by default
        mIsReceivingUpdates = false;

        // Set up the default LocationRequest parameters
        this.mLocationRequest = new LocationRequest();
        setLocationRequestParams(10000, 5000, LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
                                // Sets up the LocationRequest with an update interval of 10 seconds, a fastest
                                // update interval cap of 5 seconds and using high accuracy power priority.
    }


    /**
     * Retrieves and returns the device's cached last known location via an instance of
     * UserLocationCallback, which must be implemented by the caller.
     *
     * Location can be null in certain circumstances, for example on a new or recently
     * factory-reset device or if location services are turned off in device settings.
     */
    @SuppressLint("MissingPermission")
    public void getLastKnownLocation(final UserLocationCallback callback){
        // Re-acquire a strong reference to the calling activity and verify that it still exists and is active
        Activity activity = weakActivity.get();
        if (activity == null || activity.isFinishing() || activity.isDestroyed()) {
            // Activity is no longer valid, don't do anything
            return;
        }

        // Request the last known location from the location client
        mLocationClient.getLastLocation()
                .addOnSuccessListener(activity, new OnSuccessListener<Location>()
                {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(Location location){

                        if (location != null){
                            // Call back to the main thread with the location result
                            callback.onLocationResult(location);
                        } else {
                            // Call back to the main thread to advise of a null result
                            callback.onFailedRequest("Location request returned null");
                        }

                    }
                });
    }


    /**
     * Returns the device's current location via an instance of UserLocationCallback,
     * which must be implemented by the caller.
     *
     * Turns on location updates, retrieves the current device location then turns
     * location updates off again. This can be used if last location returns null
     * but location services are turned on, or if a more recent or accurate location
     * is needed than the one found in the device's cache.
     */
    @SuppressLint("MissingPermission")
    public void getCurrentLocationOneTime(final UserLocationCallback callback){
        if (mIsReceivingUpdates){
            callback.onFailedRequest("Device is already receiving updates");
            return;
        }

        // Set up the LocationCallback for the request
        mLocationCallback = new LocationCallback()
        {
            @Override
            public void onLocationResult(LocationResult locationResult){
                if (locationResult != null){
                    callback.onLocationResult(locationResult.getLastLocation());
                    // Stop location updates now that we have a location result
                    stopLocationUpdates();
                } else {
                    callback.onFailedRequest("Location request returned null");
                    // Stop location updates on null result
                    stopLocationUpdates();
                }
            }
        };

        // Start the request
        mLocationClient.requestLocationUpdates(mLocationRequest, mLocationCallback, null);
        // Update the request state flag
        mIsReceivingUpdates = true;
    }


    /**
     * Starts a location update request with the parameters specified by mLocationRequest and
     * returns the location result via an instance of UserLocationCallback, which must be
     * implemented by the caller.
     *
     * This is inherently power-intensive so care should be taken to balance the frequency
     * of requested updates with the need for accuracy.
     *
     * Location updates should be disabled using the stopLocationUpdates() method when no
     * longer needed, such as when the user closes or otherwise navigates away from the app.
     *
     * @see UserLocationUtility#stopLocationUpdates()
     */
    @SuppressLint("MissingPermission")
    public void getCurrentLocationUpdates(final UserLocationCallback callback){
        if (mIsReceivingUpdates){
            callback.onFailedRequest("Device is already receiving updates");
            return;
        }

        // Set up the LocationCallback for the request
        mLocationCallback = new LocationCallback()
        {
            @Override
            public void onLocationResult(LocationResult locationResult){
                if (locationResult != null){
                    callback.onLocationResult(locationResult.getLastLocation());
                } else {
                    callback.onFailedRequest("Location request returned null");
                }
            }
        };

        // Start the request
        mLocationClient.requestLocationUpdates(mLocationRequest, mLocationCallback, null);
        // Update the request state flag
        mIsReceivingUpdates = true;
    }


    /**
     * Returns the best available location via an instance of UserLocationCallback, which
     * must be implemented by the caller.
     *
     * Checks if last known location is available. If unavailable (null) then a single
     * location update is requested instead.
     *
     * If current location is also unavailable (due to a disabled service for example)
     * then an onFailedRequest callback is executed to be handled by the caller.
     *
     * This method should be preferred over the getLastKnownLocation() and
     * getCurrentLocationOneTime() methods in most use cases.
     *
     * @param   callback An interface which must be implemented by the caller in order to
     *          receive the results of the location request.
     */
    @SuppressLint("MissingPermission")
    public void getSmartLocation(final UserLocationCallback callback){
        // Re-acquire a strong reference to the calling activity and verify that it still exists and is active
        Activity activity = weakActivity.get();
        if (activity == null || activity.isFinishing() || activity.isDestroyed()) {
            // Activity is no longer valid, don't do anything
            return;
        }

        // Request the last known location from the location client
        mLocationClient.getLastLocation()
                .addOnSuccessListener(activity, new OnSuccessListener<Location>()
                {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(Location location){

                        if (location != null){

                            // Call back to the main thread with the location result
                            Log.i("getSmartLocation()", "Location provided by getLastLocation()");
                            callback.onLocationResult(location);

                        } else {
                            // Location result is null or so request location updates to attempt
                            // to get the device's current location.

                            // Set up the LocationCallback for the request
                            mLocationCallback = new LocationCallback()
                            {
                                @Override
                                public void onLocationResult(LocationResult locationResult){
                                    if (locationResult != null){
                                        callback.onLocationResult(locationResult.getLastLocation());
                                        Log.i("getSmartLocation()", "Location provided by requestLocationUpdates()");
                                        // Stop location updates now that we have a location result
                                        stopLocationUpdates();
                                    } else {
                                        callback.onFailedRequest("Location request returned null");
                                        // Stop location updates on null result
                                        stopLocationUpdates();
                                    }
                                }
                            };

                            // Start the request
                            mLocationClient.requestLocationUpdates(mLocationRequest, mLocationCallback, null);
                            // Update the request state flag
                            mIsReceivingUpdates = true;
                        }

                    }
                });

    }


    /**
     * Simple check to see if the required permission has been granted.
     *
     * @return  true if permission granted, false if not.
     */
    public boolean checkPermissionGranted(){

        int permissionState = ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(mContext,
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION);

        return permissionState == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;
    }


    /**
     * Explicitly requests permission to access the device's fine location.
     *
     * Determines if additional rationale should be provided to the user, displays it if
     * so then initiates a permission request via a call to startPermissionRequest().
     *
     * @param   requestCode A package-defined int constant to identify the request.
     *                      It is returned to the onRequestPermissionsResult callback
     *                      which must be implemented by the caller.
     */
    public void requestPermission(int requestCode){
        // Re-acquire a strong reference to the calling activity and verify that it still exists and is active
        Activity activity = weakActivity.get();
        if (activity == null || activity.isFinishing() || activity.isDestroyed()) {
            // Activity is no longer valid, don't do anything
            return;
        }

        boolean shouldProvideRationale = ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(
                activity, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION);

        if (shouldProvideRationale){

            // Provide additional rationale to the user. This would happen if the user denied the request
            // previously but didn't tick the "Don't ask again" checkbox.
            RationaleAlertDialog dialog = new RationaleAlertDialog(activity);
            dialog.displayAlert();

            // Request permission
            startPermissionRequest(requestCode);

        } else {

            // Request permission. It's possible this can be auto-answered if the device policy sets
            // the permission in a given state or the user denied the request previously and ticked
            // the "Don't ask again" checkbox.
            startPermissionRequest(requestCode);

        }

    }

    /**
     * Called by requestPermission() to initiate a permission request
     *
     * @param   requestCode the request code passed in by requestPermission()
     * @see UserLocationUtility#requestPermission(int)
     */
    private void startPermissionRequest(int requestCode){
        // Re-acquire a strong reference to the calling activity and verify that it still exists and is active
        Activity activity = weakActivity.get();
        if (activity == null || activity.isFinishing() || activity.isDestroyed()) {
            // Activity is no longer valid, don't do anything
            return;
        }

        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(activity,
                new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},
                requestCode);
                // requestCode is an int constant. The onRequestPermissionsResult callback
                // gets the result of the request.
    }


    /**
     * Checks if all required location settings are satisfied
     *
     * If the settings are not satisfied a dialog requesting the user enable the required
     * settings will be displayed. The result of the request can be checked in
     * onActivityResult() in the calling Activity if necessary.
     */
    public void checkDeviceSettings(){
        // Re-acquire a strong reference to the calling activity and verify that it still exists and is active
        final Activity activity = weakActivity.get();
        if (activity == null || activity.isFinishing() || activity.isDestroyed()) {
            // Activity is no longer valid, don't do anything
            return;
        }

        // Create a settings request builder and pass it the LocationRequest
        LocationSettingsRequest.Builder builder = new LocationSettingsRequest.Builder()
                .addLocationRequest(mLocationRequest);

        // Create a settings client
        SettingsClient client= LocationServices.getSettingsClient(mContext);

        // Create a Task from the client
        Task<LocationSettingsResponse> task = client.checkLocationSettings(builder.build());

        // Query the result of the Task to determine if the required location settings are satisfied
        task.addOnSuccessListener(activity, new OnSuccessListener<LocationSettingsResponse>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(LocationSettingsResponse locationSettingsResponse) {
                // Location settings are satisfied, no need to take any action
                Log.i(TAG, "Location settings satisfied");
            }
        });
        task.addOnFailureListener(activity, new OnFailureListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                if (e instanceof ResolvableApiException){
                    // Location settings are not satisfied, display a dialog to the user
                    // requesting the settings to be enabled
                    Log.e(TAG, "Location settings not satisfied. Attempting to resolve...");
                    try{
                        ResolvableApiException resolvable = (ResolvableApiException) e;
                        // Show the dialog
                        resolvable.startResolutionForResult(activity, 1);
                    } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException sendException){
                        // Ignore the error.
                    }

                }
            }
        });

    }


    /**
     * Determines if location updates are currently active or not
     *
     * @return  true if receiving location updates, false if not.
     */
    public boolean isReceivingUpdates(){
        return mIsReceivingUpdates;
    }


    /**
     * Stops location updates from being received.
     *
     * This should be called in the calling Activity's onPause() method so
     * that location updates don't continue in the background when the user
     * navigates away from the app.
     */
    public void stopLocationUpdates(){

        if (mLocationCallback != null) {
            mLocationClient.removeLocationUpdates(mLocationCallback);
            mIsReceivingUpdates = false;
            Log.i(TAG, "Location updates removed");
        }

    }


    /**
     * Resumes location updates if they have previously been set up
     *
     * This should be called in the calling Activity's onResume() method if
     * you want your app to continue to receive location updates when it resumes
     *
     * @see UserLocationUtility#stopLocationUpdates()
     */
    @SuppressLint("MissingPermission")
    public void resumeLocationUpdates(){

        if (mLocationCallback != null) {
            mLocationClient.requestLocationUpdates(mLocationRequest, mLocationCallback, null);
            mIsReceivingUpdates = true;
            Log.i(TAG, "Location updates resumed");
        }

    }


    /**
     * Provides a way for a calling Activity to set or change the default parameters of
     * the LocationRequest object to suit its needs.
     *
     * @param interval          Set the desired interval for active location updates, in milliseconds.
     * @param fastestInterval   Explicitly set the fastest interval for location updates, in
     *                          milliseconds. This controls the fastest rate at which your
     *                          application will receive location updates.
     * @param priority          Set the priority of the request. Use with a priority constant such as
     *                          LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY. No other values are accepted.
     */
    public void setLocationRequestParams(long interval, long fastestInterval, int priority){

        if (mLocationRequest == null) {
            mLocationRequest = new LocationRequest();
        }

        mLocationRequest.setInterval(interval);
        mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(fastestInterval);
        mLocationRequest.setPriority(priority);

    }


    /**
     * Returns a List object containing the address information for the supplied
     * Location object. Will be null if no address found. The caller should
     * implement a UserLocationCallback to receive and handle the result.
     *
     * @param   location    A Location object containing latitude and longitude.
     * @param   callback    An interface which must be implemented by the caller in order to
     *                      receive the results of the request.
     */
    public void getAddressList(Location location, UserLocationCallback callback){

        mGeocoder = new Geocoder(mContext, Locale.getDefault());
        List<Address> addressList = null;

        try {

            addressList = mGeocoder.getFromLocation(
                    location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude(),
                    1); // We only want one address to be returned.

        } catch (IOException e) {
            // Catch network or other IO problems
            callback.onFailedRequest("Geocoder not available");
            return;
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            // Catch invalid latitude or longitude values
            callback.onFailedRequest("Invalid latitude or longitude");
            return;
        }

        // Handle case where no address is found
        if (addressList == null || addressList.size() == 0) {
            callback.onFailedRequest("No address found");
        } else {
            // Return the address list
            callback.onAddressResult(addressList);
        }

    }


    /**
     * Returns a String containing the requested address element or null if not found
     *
     * @param   elementCode A package-defined int constant representing the specific
     *                      address element to return.
     * @param   location    A Location object containing a latitude and longitude.
     *
     * @return  String containing the requested address element if found, a reason for
     *          failure if necessary or null if address element doesn't exist.
     */
    public String getAddressElement(int elementCode, Location location){

        mGeocoder = new Geocoder(mContext, Locale.getDefault());
        List<Address> addressList;
        Address address;
        String elementString = null;

        try {

            addressList = mGeocoder.getFromLocation(
                    location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude(),
                    1); // We only want one address to be returned.

        } catch (IOException e) {
            // Catch network or other IO problems
            return "Geocoder not available. Check network connection.";
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            // Catch invalid latitude or longitude values
            return "Invalid latitude or longitude";
        }

        // Handle case where no address is found
        if (addressList == null || addressList.size() == 0){
            return "Sorry, no address found for this location";
        } else {
            // Create the Address object from the address list
            address = addressList.get(0);
        }

        // Get the specific address element requested by the caller
        switch (elementCode){

            case AddressCodes.ADMIN_AREA:
                elementString = address.getAdminArea();
                break;
            case AddressCodes.CITY_NAME:
                elementString = address.getLocality();
                break;
            case AddressCodes.COUNTRY_CODE:
                elementString = address.getCountryCode();
                break;
            case AddressCodes.COUNTRY_NAME:
                elementString = address.getCountryName();
                break;
            case AddressCodes.FEATURE_NAME:
                elementString = address.getFeatureName();
                break;
            case AddressCodes.FULL_ADDRESS:
                elementString = address.toString();
                break;
            case AddressCodes.PHONE_NUMBER:
                elementString = address.getPhone();
                break;
            case AddressCodes.POST_CODE:
                elementString = address.getPostalCode();
                break;
            case AddressCodes.PREMISES:
                elementString = address.getPremises();
                break;
            case AddressCodes.STREET_ADDRESS:
                elementString = address.getThoroughfare();
                break;
            case AddressCodes.SUB_ADMIN_AREA:
                elementString = address.getSubAdminArea();
                break;
            case AddressCodes.SUB_THOROUGHFARE:
                elementString = address.getSubThoroughfare();
                break;
            default:
                elementString = "Invalid element code";
                break;
        }

        return elementString;
    }


}
```

And here's the UserLocationCallback interface...

```
public interface UserLocationCallback {

    void onLocationResult(Location location);
    void onAddressResult(List<Address> addressList);
    void onFailedRequest(String result);

}
```